# Method for creating lengthy drop down select list in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, enums

I want to create a select drop down in a rails form_for which will have ~40 options to it. What would be the best way to build this in a Rails app? My thoughts were an enum on the model and then use `#options_from_collection_for_select` helper.

I just wondered whether there might be a Rails 'standard practice' for such a situation?

Comment: What are the options, do they matter to the DB? You could make another table with a relation, which is pretty useful if for more dynamic lists. Enum can be useful if you have fixed data, and you can get the list of allowed values to make a select, or if you want strings in the DB, just have a list of allowed strings in the model.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, it's not a good solution to make an `enum` attribute for such variants quantity. It's not a best architecture solution. I suggest you create directory model with belongs_to reference at main entity.